# command not found error on calling oozie action via shell script

Tags: shell, oozie

I'm trying to trigger Oozie job through shell script. But on execution of shell script am getting the below error:

> "command not found" error in the line: ooziejob =$(oozie job -oozie
>   http://oozieserver:port/oozie -config
>   /root/SqoopWrapper1/sqoop_job.properties -run);

My shell script consisting of oozie command is;

```
input=/root/SqoopWrapper1/InputFile.txt

echo "internal field sep"

IFS='|'

while read SourceDB db_name Mysql_table hdfsdir libpath

do

echo "do...while"
        if [ SourceDB = Mysql ]
        then
        driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        jdbcUri = jdbc:mysql://host:3306
        Mysql_table = WrapperTbl
        UserName = ****
        Password = ****
        fi

echo "Oozie command exe"

ooziejob =$(oozie job -oozie http://oozieserver:port/oozie -config /root/SqoopWrapper1/sqoop_job.properties -run);

echo $ooziejob;

done < $input


exit 0
```

Comment: The most probable reason is, Shell action is launched as mapper job and runs on a node on the cluster. The node on which it is running does not have oozie client installed. You might consider using ssh action and pointing to a node where oozie client is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space before the equal-sign.

BTW, if you post this kind of questions, you should always say what shell and what OS you are using.